# Diagnosing a leaky top load Whirlpool washing machine

Tags: leak, washing-machine

Looking for help w diagnosis. It was running, I think on drain or spin and I heard water leaking—there was water running out from the bottom. Tipped over and the water pump was dusty but dry. The metal part in the middle —I guess the transmission— was wet and appeared slightly rusty.

Please tell me if I’m wrong: if the pump is dry then the pump is good right?

And, how is it possible to tell whether it needs a new center gasket or an entirely new transmission?

Model WTW 5500SQ0

[image]

[image]